# How to make file upload in struts2 optional?

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I'm building a web application with Struts2. There's a small part that involves File Upload. The File Upload works well. However a `NullPointerException` is thrown when I choose to NOT upload a file. The only way I can handle this in code, is by `catch(NullPointerException NPE)` . And a part of the code gets repeated. I wish to avoid this.

Is there any way I can handle a `NULL` for a file upload in Struts2?

My HTML file:

```
<s:file style="height:auto;width:550px;display:inline;align:center;" name="userImage" cssClass="text input" onchange="checkFile(this)"/>
```

My Java action code which handles this:

```
try{
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);}

catch(NullPointerException NPE){//if I choose to NOT upload a file}
catch(Exception E){//some code}
```

I've tried the `getUserImage()==null` but it does not help. Do I absolutely *have* to handle the rest of the code *inside* the `catch(NullPointerException NPE)` block?

Comment: So which object is `null`?

Comment: `userImage` (mentioned in the HTML code) is mapped to a variable in my action class, also called `userImage` . Now, when I choose to NOT upload a file, an NPE is thrown. So I'm guessing `userImage` gets the `null`.

Comment: Don't guess, check it.

Comment: I did - no NPE is thrown when I DO upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the `NullPointerException` is thrown at one of the following two lines

```
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
```

because `this.userImageFileName` and/or `this.userImage` is `null`, if you do not upload a file.

So, try this:

```
if(this.userImageFileName != null && this.userImage != null){
   File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
   FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
}
```

Now, no `NullPointerException` should occure, since you checked for `null` in advance.